# await is a reserved word Asyncdata vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am trying to use axios but I keep getting await is a reserved word. I am using vue.js.

```js
import axios from '~/plugins/axios'
export default {
  layout: 'dashboard',
  asyncData ({ params, error }) {
    let { data } = await axios.get('/api/users')
    return { users: data }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you seeing this error?

Comment: At the bottom console

Comment: Well, for one, you cannot use `await` unless your function is marked `async`, ie `async asyncData ({ params, error })`

Comment: hey thanks adding async infont works